# add programmatically a checkbox to a stackpanel

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am trying to add programmatically a checkbox into a stackpanel in an wpf application using Visual basic.

this syntax: `aStackPanel.Children.add(image1)` works great for objects like images or textblocks. However when it comes to the checkbox I am getting following error; that the value type checkbox cannot be converted to the system.windows.UIElement.

Can someone propose another way to add the checkbox to the stackpanel programmatically?

thanks

Comment: Show us the relevant code.

Comment: Something is not right here because the WPF Checkbox inherits from UIElement. You must have something else called Checkbox..?

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to add a WinForms Checkbox and not a WPF Checkbox.

Comment: You do need to show us the code, and the type for the checkbox. If you have an imports that is using System.Windows.Form then you are using the wrong control. As it stands right now all we can do is guess.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help. Indeed I had an imports using System.Windows.Form.

I removed it and now I can add the checkbox in my stackpanel.

A lesson learnt for me:

The reason for using the System.Windows.Form import is because I am calling the class `FolderBrowserDialog`. I simply has to include the Namespace to use it without the preceded import so it becomes: `Forms.FolderBrowserDialog`.

Comment: Another remark: Which is the equivalent to FolderBrowserDialog class so I don't have to rely at Forms Namespace?